# How to get users by custom attributes in keycloak?

Tags: keycloak

I know that there is admin APIs to get the list of users which returns the user representation array.

```
GET /admin/realms/{realm}/groups/{id}/members
```

returns

```
https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/2.5/rest-api/index.html#_userrepresentation
```

but is there a way to get users by custom attribute ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current Keycloak API version is 4.8 and there is API: 
*Get users Returns a list of users, filtered according to query parameters*

```
GET /{realm}/users
```

See doc: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/4.8/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource

Only this "search" is available from the API. If you need search by user attributes, then you need to implement it in your own code.

Comment: Link seems to be broken - 404

Answer (score 23):

This is enabled out of the box from Keycloak version **15.1.0**

Using `GET /{realm}/users` API,  parameter `q` is introduced: *A query to search for custom attributes, in the format 'key1:value2 key2:value2'*

```
curl 'http://{{keycloak_url}}/auth/admin/realms/{{realm}}/users?q=phone:123456789'
```

You can also combine several attributes within this parameter using space `' '` delimiter

```
curl 'http://{{keycloak_url}}/auth/admin/realms/{{realm}}/users?q=phone:123456789 country:USA'
```

Docs: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.1/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource

Comment: This works but for a large database is really slow, any alternatives? I am using v17.0

Answer (score 18):

This is not possible by default, but Keycloak offers the possibility to extend its functionalities via a system of Service Provider Interfaces which is very easy to implement.

Here is an example of new route that allows to search by custom attributes :

```
public class SearchByAttributeResourceProvider implements RealmResourceProvider {
    private KeycloakSession session;

    public SearchByAttributeResourceProvider(KeycloakSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getResource() {
        return this;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("search-by-stuff/{stuffValue}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public List<UserRepresentation> getUsersByStuff(@PathParam("stuffValue") String stuffValue) {
        return session
                .users()
                .searchForUserByUserAttribute("stuff", stuffValue, session.getContext().getRealm())
                                .stream()  
                                .map(userModel -> ModelToRepresentation.toRepresentation(session, session.getContext().getRealm(), userModel))
                                .collect(toList());
    } 

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

You'll find more details here : https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_extensions_rest

Comment: Thank you. This basically works. For me there was the problem though, that Jackson needed to access fields, after the transaction was committed. In my case, I was only interested in the ids, so I could just extract them and return plain Strings instead. In the Keycloak examples, they return DTOs instead of Entities (CompanyRepresentation instead of Company for example). See [here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/a77c35ea8fc2157439c3d5d5787de760dc0cbb14/examples/providers/domain-extension/src/main/java/org/keycloak/examples/domainextension/spi/impl/ExampleServiceImpl.java#L59)

Comment: Yes sorry, you must return representations not models, so you need to map the users using ModelToRepresentation.toRepresentation(). I updated my response.

Comment: Thanks for this wonderful answer! I was wondering whether it is possible to search within a group? It looks straight forward to do this after fetching the users with a search, but I'm afraid that would be to memory/cpu intensive.

Comment: You could retrieve the Entity Manager session.getProvider(JpaConnectionProvider.class).getEntityManager(); and build a custom query to filter users by groups/roles

Comment: Time passes and APIs change: stackoverflow.com/a/71838958/717732 ; since your answer is at the moment quite high-ranked, please add a note about which VERSION of Keycloak you wrote the answer for. Depending on the version, it may be an overkill for simple cases. Still, knowing that you can add/customize the lookup is a very important bit in tough cases, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

With latest version of keycloak (18.01), we have api in

```
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    List<UserRepresentation> searchByAttributes(@QueryParam("q") String searchQuery);
```

The query param is of format 'key:value' . Using this we can get list of all users by custom attributes

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from the endpoint calls presented on this answer.

---

**Keycloak versions from 15.1.0 upwards**

Although not mentioned on the [release notes](https://www.keycloak.org/2021/12/keycloak-1510-released.html) it is possible after Keycloak version 15.1.0 (as pointed out by [@Darko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71838958/1366871)) to search users by custom attributes, introduced with this [commit](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/commit/5b0986e490090433658e9a1e607c0e248f4cc756). As one can now see on the [GET /{realm}/users](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.1/rest-api/index.html#_getusers) endpoint of the Keycloak Admin Rest API:

[image]

Form example:

```
curl 'https://${KEYCLOAL_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}/users?q=employeeNumber:444555'
```

---

**Keycloak versions before 15.1.0**

For version before 15.1.0, out-of-the-box you can use the [Keycloak Admin API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.1/rest-api/index.html#_getusers) endpoint:

```
GET /{realm}/users
```

one can read that :

> Get users Returns a list of users, filtered according to query
> parameters

those (optional) query parameters being:

- briefRepresentation (boolean);
- email (string);
- first (string);
- firstName (string);
- lastName (string);
- max (Maximum results size (defaults to 100)) (integer);
- search (A String contained in username, first or last name, or email);
- username (string).

As you can see you cannot search for custom attributes. A not so great solution is to get all the users (*max=-1*), and filter afterwards by the custom attribute.

The other option (pointed out by [@Lucas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61347345/1366871)) is to extend Keycloak functionality by adding your own custom Service Provider Interfaces (SPI) and adding your custom endpoint. There you can take advantage of the [searchForUserByUserAttribute](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/9.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/storage/user/UserQueryProvider.html#searchForUserByUserAttribute-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-org.keycloak.models.RealmModel-) method from the [UserQueryProvider](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/9.0/javadocs/org/keycloak/storage/user/UserQueryProvider.html) interface.

**Step-by-step with Keycloak Admin API versions from 15.1.0 upwards**

To use the Keycloak Admin REST API, you need an *access token* from a user with the proper permissions. For now, I will be using the `admin` user from the `master` realm, and later explain how to use another user:

```bash
curl “https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token” \
    -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
    -d "username=${ADMIN_NAME}” \
    -d "password=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}" \
    -d "grant_type=password"
```

You get a JSON response with the admin's token. Extract the value of property `access_token` from that response. Let us save it in the variable `$ACCESS_TOKEN` for later reference.

To get the list of users from your realm `$REALM_NAME` with a given set of attributes (*i.e.,* `${ATTRIBUTES}`).

```bash
curl -X GET “https://${KEYCLOAK_HOST}/auth/admin/realms/${REALM_NAME}/users?q=${ATTRIBUTES}” \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     -H "Authorization: bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}”
```

I have the aforementioned steps coded in the script [getUserByAttributes.sh](https://github.com/dreamcrash/StackOverflow-/blob/main/Keycloak/RestAdminAPI/Users/getUserByAttributes.sh) on my GitHub repo for those that are interested. An example :

```
sh getUserByAttributes.sh localhost:8080 admin admin test_realm 'employeeNumber:4445 something:a'
```

**Assigning the proper user permissions**

For those that do not want to get an *access token* from the `master` admin user, you can get it from another user but that user needs the permission `manage-users` from the `realm-management` client. For that you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67168174/1366871) on how to do it

Answer (score 0):

You can filter keycloak users using their custom attributes by passing the 'q' get parameter:

IN SUMMARY:

```
<get-users-url>?q=key1:value1 key2:value2
```

EXAMPLE:

```
   curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8080/admin/realms/realm-name/users?q=key1:value1 key2:value2' \
        --header 'Authorization: Bearer <your-token>'
```