# Is it possible to configure user in realm with rights to read/modify roles and users

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Is it possible to configure in keycloak realm (but not in a master realm) to give users access to admin api.
I want to be able as a keycloak user to configure other user roles/scopes etc. 
It will be done from fronted service so it cannot be done using service account.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to configure in keycloak realm (but not in a master
> realm) to give users access to admin api.

Yes, for that you need to:

**(Old Keycloak UI)**

- Go to the target Realm;
- Go to users and click on the user to add the roles;
- Switch to the tab `Role Mappings`
- On the `Client Roles` dropdown menu select `realm-management`
- and assign the roles accordingly.

[image]

**(New Keycloak UI)**

- Go to the target Realm;
- Go to users and click on the user to add the roles;
- Click on `Assign role`
- In `Search by role name` type the desired role
- Select the role and assign it

[image]