# How to find keycloak users without attribute?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54667407/how-to-get-users-by-custom-attributes-in-keycloak), I would like to get all the users without a given attribute.

Is there some special (undocumented?) notation for [the `q` query parameter of the `/{realm}/users` endpoint](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.1/rest-api/#_users_resource) to search for absent attributes, or is this just not supported at all?

Comment: what you mean "absent attributes"? By the "q" parameter or other search what kind of information for users? I don't know what is you looking for.

Comment: I simply want to list all users, that do **not** have attribute `foo`, for example.

Comment: As I know no way GET all users API now showsing user's attribute. It only shows when GET specific user API. [This is my demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73105467/keycloak-user-attributes-that-are-specific-to-groups/73106895#73106895)